# Visa for 3-month internship in Switzerland

Tags: visa, switzerland, internship

I am a non European currently studying in Germany and have a residence permit here. I want to do an internship in Switzerland for 3 months. Do I need to apply for a Swiss visa or is the German residence permit sufficient?

Comment: Is it a paid internship?

Comment: @phoog: yes, a stipend

Answer (score 1):

According to the International Association for the Exchange of Students for Technical Experience, [unless you are from Japan, New Zealand, Singapore, or Malaysia you will need a visa](https://www.iaeste.ch/swiss-employers/student-placement/visa/):

> The visa will be transferred to a Swiss embassy in the country of residence of the trainee and needs to be picked up there. Entering Switzerland for working purposes without a valid visa is not permitted and a visa cannot be obtained in Switzerland.

Your German visa authorizes you to travel to other Schengen states for up to 90 days in any 180-day period, but it doesn't authorize you to work in other Schengen states.